# Which sobolev embedding gives $W_p^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W_{n-\varepsilon}^1(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand a corollary of the Rellich Kondrachov theorem:

Corollary Let $\Omega \in C^1$ be bounded. Then, for $1 \leq p<\infty$,
$$
W_p^1(\Omega) \stackrel{c}{\hookrightarrow} L_p(\Omega)
$$
PRoOF. If $p<n$, then $p<p_*$ by definition, and the assertion follows directly from Theorem 4.13. If $p \geq n$, then this observation implies
$$
W_p^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W_{n-\varepsilon}^1(\Omega) \stackrel{c}{\hookrightarrow} L_q(\Omega)
$$
for $1 \leq q<(n-\varepsilon)_*$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $(n-\varepsilon)_* \nearrow \infty$ as $\varepsilon \searrow 0$, the assertion follows.

However, I don't understand the part of the proof that claims $W_p^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W_{n-\varepsilon}^1(\Omega)$. So we had a Sobolev embedding theorem and the Morrey theorem proven before we got to the Reliich Embedding theorem, but I don't see how to apply those go give us $W_p^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W_{n-\varepsilon}^1(\Omega)$.

So the Sobolev Embedding theorem that was already proven is the following:

Theorem (Sobolev's Embedding Theorem). (a) Let $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\Omega=(0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ or let $\Omega \in C^m$ be such that $\partial \Omega$ is compact. For $k, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq p, q<\infty$ with
$$
\frac{1}{p} \geq \frac{1}{q} \geq \frac{1}{p}-\frac{m-k}{n}>0
$$
we have
$$
W_p^m(\Omega) \stackrel{d}{\hookrightarrow} W_q^k(\Omega)
$$
(b) Let $\Omega \in C^m$ be a bounded domain. For $k, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ with
$$
0 \leq k<m-\frac{n}{p}
$$
we have
$$
W_p^m(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C^k(\bar{\Omega})
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $W^1_p (\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^1_{n-\epsilon}(\Omega)$ can be understood as follows. Since $p \geq n$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ you get $p > n-\epsilon$. Therefore, the inclusion $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^{n-\epsilon}(\Omega)$ holds as set and also continuously. So you get an inclusion $W^1_p (\Omega) \subset W^1_{n-\epsilon}(\Omega)$ as sets and also continuously.

For bonus here is another way to conclude the argument for $W^1_p (\Omega) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$ in the case $ p \geq n$.

- If $p =n$, the Rellich-Kondrachov embedding becomes
  $$
  W^1_p(\Omega) \subset \bigcap_{1 < q < \infty} L^q(\Omega).
  $$
  Using the Riesz-Fréchet-Kolmogorov theorem it is rather elementary to show that
  $$
  1 \leq p < q \leq \infty \Longrightarrow L^q(\Omega) \hookrightarrow  \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega).
  $$
  Putting together those facts you get that $W^1_p (\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$ is compact.
- If $p > n$, use the Morrey embedding to obtain
  $$
  W^1_p(\Omega) \hookrightarrow  C^{0,\alpha}(\overline \Omega) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(\Omega) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)
  $$
  for some $0 < \alpha < 1$.